# How to make a CodeBlock in nextjs Website blog? Something like shown in image

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

It is about adding a code block in the next js.

```py
def gree(name):
   """
   this function greets to the person passed in as parameter 
   """
   print("Hello, " + name + ". Good morning!")
```

Code:

```
import React from "react";
import { CopyBlock,dracula } from "react-code-blocks";

function CodeBlockk() {
  return (
    <div>
    <h3>GeeksforGeeks Code</h3>
    <CopyBlock
    text="print('GeeksforGeeks') \n dfewf"

    language='python'
    showLineNumbers='true'
    wrapLines
    theme={dracula}
    />
    </div>
  );
}
export default CodeBlockk;
```

Comment: There is no image shown.

Comment: Image: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMO2y.png

Answer (score 1):

Based on documentation `showLineNumbers` prop is boolean but you have entered `'true'` as a string which may cause the conflict.
try this:

```js
function CodeBlockk() {
return (
    <div>
    <h3>GeeksforGeeks Code</h3>
    <CopyBlock
    text="print('GeeksforGeeks') \n dfewf"
    language='python'
    showLineNumbers={true}
    wrapLines
    theme={dracula}
    />
    </div>
);
}
export default CodeBlockk;
```

Answer (score 0):

`showLineNumbers` indicates whether or not to show line numbers and data type is    `boolean` and default value is `true`.
Here's [the answer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

I have got the solution to my problem.
Here is the solution.

```js
import React from "react";
import Code from "../../components/Code";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Prism from "prismjs";
import "prismjs/themes/prism-tomorrow.css";

export default function Page(props) {
  useEffect(() => {
    Prism.highlightAll();
  }, []);

  var code1 = `var x, y, z;  // Declare 3 variables
  x = 5;    // Assign the value 5 to x
  y = 6;    // Assign the value 6 to y
  z = x + y;  // Assign the sum of x and y to z
  
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
  "The value of z is " + z + ".";`;

  var code2 = `print("Hello world")
print("Hello world")`;

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center">
      <main className="max-w-2xl lg:w-[800px] sm:w-[800px] w-72">
        <pre className="line-numbers">
          <code className="language-jsx">{code1}</code>
        </pre>
        <pre className="line-numbers">
          <code className="language-jsx">{code2}</code>
        </pre>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).